# Infragistics WebHierarchicalDataGrid - Custom style on child bands when Databind to IList?

Tags: data-binding, datagrid, infragistics, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to setup some custom styles and TemplateDataFields on the child band level of the Infragistics Hierarchical DataGrid. I'm binding the control to an IList which has sub lists. The control will work fine (display the parent table and expand out the child tables) when I configure it to AutoGenerateBands. But I need to be have custom headers, and TemplateDataFields on the child tables.

Here is my aspx:

```
      <ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid ID="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1" runat="server"   AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          AutoGenerateBands="false" DataKeyFields="DataSourceId" Width="700px"   Height="700px">
        <ExpandCollapseAnimation SlideOpenDirection="Auto" SlideOpenDuration="300" SlideCloseDirection="Auto"
            SlideCloseDuration="300" />


    <Columns>        
        <ig:BoundDataField  DataFieldName="DataSourceId" Key="DataSourceId" Header-Text="Data Source Id" Hidden="true"/>                        
        <ig:BoundDataField  DataFieldName="DataSrc" Key="DataSrc" Header-Text="Data Source" />
        <ig:BoundDataField  DataFieldName="DataSrcType" Key="DataSrcType" Header-Text="Activity Type" />
        <ig:BoundDataField  DataFieldName="Reporting" Key="Reporting" Header-Text="Reporting?" />
        <ig:BoundDataField  DataFieldName="LastUpdtSrc" Key="LastUpdtSrc" Header-Text="Last Update Source" />
        <ig:BoundDataField  DataFieldName="LastUpdtDate" Key="LastUpdtDate" Header-Text="Last Update Date" />
        <ig:TemplateDataField Key="Priority" Header-Text="Priority"> </ig:TemplateDataField>
    </Columns>

     <Bands> 
        <ig:Band DataMember="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1" Key="DataSourceId">
            <Columns>
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="DataSourceId" Key="DataSourceId" Header-Text="Data Source Id" Hidden="true" />
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="OriginalSrc" Key="OriginalSrc" Header-Text="Original Source" />
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="LastUpdtDate" Key="LastUpdtDate" Header-Text="Last Update Date" />
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="RecordsCount" Key="RecordsCount" Header-Text="Records Count" />
            </Columns>
        </ig:Band>
    </Bands>


        <Behaviors>
            <ig:Paging PagerAppearance="Bottom" PageSize="50" Enabled="true" />
            <ig:Sorting SortingMode="Single" Enabled="true">
            </ig:Sorting>
        </Behaviors>
        </ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>
```

And here is how I bind the data in the Page Load:

```
    this.WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.DataSource = GetLastUpdatedEvents().OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdtDate);

    this.WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.DataBind();
```

This code produces a nicely formatted parent table, and displays the expand arrows on the correct rows. Once clicked the pacifier will spin but no child table is displayed.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks,

-Will

Comment: Ok, so I discovered this helpful example: http://community.infragistics.com/forums/t/35449.aspx
and figured out what was wrong.

The DataMember property on the child band needed to be set to the property name of the sub-lists on the IList object.

    <ig:Band DataMember="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1" Key="DataSourceId">

should be:

    <ig:Band DataMember="OriginalDataSrcs" Key="DataSourceId">

where OriginalDataSrcs is the property name of the sub list.

Hopefully this example will be helpful to someone out there.

-Will

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it, as this helped me and I'm sure it would help someone else.